# ImportError: cannot import name 'search' from 'googlesearch'

Tags: python, pip, google-search, kali-linux

I installed all required libraries.
Already having installed google, google-search, google-cloud, googlesearch-python, beautifulsoup4.But after all the things I got this error:

```py
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sigit", line 9, in <module>
    from googlesearch import search
ImportError: cannot import name 'search' from 'googlesearch' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/googlesearch/__init__.py)**
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really weird because imports that `pypi.org` recommends doesn't work at all. I dug into files of this library and this solution worked for me:

```py
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch

search_engine = GoogleSearch()
response_object = search_engine.search('test')
print(response_object)
```

On `pypi.org` the latest version is not old, so it shouldn't be deprecated.

**EDIT**

Here's the exact example I figured out: https://pypi.org/project/google-search/.
But is doesn't give any result. That's another weird thing. I recommend you to leave alone this libraries and find some good, free to use google search engine api.